# How to check particular value in Arraylist in Mulesoft?

Tags: arraylist, mule, mule-component

This is my ArrayList -

```
[  
   {  
      AccountNumber=123456,
      Amount=257710.06
   },
   {  
      AccountNumber=845679,
      Amount=3672351.06
   }
]
```

Here, I want to check whether the account number 123456 is in the list or not.
I have used "Choice" component, because I want to create another list with searched account numbers. This is my code-

```
 <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[flowVars.investOneList.contains(123456)]">
            <logger message="Account number is present" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="Account number is not present" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
```

Here, my logger prints "Account number is not present". My code is not able to find the account number, although it is there in the list.
Could anyone please help me out?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `List.contains(...)` you will need to map the variable you have like this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
flowVars.investOneList map $.AccountNumber
```

Which will output `[123456, 845679]` as the `payload` (you can set to something else if you want). Then you can do this in your choice router:

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[payload.contains(123456)]">
            <logger message="Account number is present" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="Account number is not present" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
```

But you could do the whole thing in MEL by using the `dw()` function like this:

```
...
<when expression="dw('(flowVars.investOneList map $.AccountNumber) contains 123456')">
...
```

And that will prevent  you from needed an intermediate calculation just to get a list of the account numbers.

Comment: Thanks @jerney. Your solution is working for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jerney. I had the same use case but i want amount value for dynamic key(ex: '123456')

Comment: Map amount instead of account number